# Finding solutions using trigonometric identities

Tags: trigonometry

I have an exam tomorrow and it is highly likely that there will be a trig identity on it. To practice I tried this identity:

$$2 \sin 5x\cos 4x-\sin x = \sin9x$$

*We solved the identity* but we had to move terms from one side to another.

**My question is: what are the things that you can and cannot do with trig identities?**

And what things are **must not** when doing trig identities?

Thank you

Comment: This is not an identity (false for x=0. It is an equation whose roots are to be found.

Comment: Sorry about that. I accidentally added a "+" between $sin5x$ and $cos4x$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Those are very general questions: what "can you do" and what "can't you do"...in terms of using trig identities:**

What you *can do* is use an identity to replace one expression with its strict *equivalent*, as determined by the *identity* in question. It's simply grounded in "substituting one expression for its equivalent", which is legitimate beyond just its handiness with utilizing trig identities to transform one expression to an equivalent expression.

You *can* algebraically manipulate equations involving trigonometric expressions in any way that is "legal" for manipulating *any* equation.

So for a simple example, ${1-\sin^2\theta} = \cos^2 \theta$ because we know the identity:

$$\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta = 1.$$ We do not change this equivalence when we manipulate it to get: $$\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta = 1 \iff \cos^2\theta = 1 - \sin^2\theta$$

---

***In the identity you solved, you can use:***

---

$$\sin c+\sin d=2\sin\frac{c+d}2\cos\frac{c-d}2$$

Applied here: $$\sin9x+\sin x=2\sin\frac{9x+x}2\cos\frac{9x-x}2=2\sin5x\cos4x$$

---

$$2\sin a\cos b=\sin(a+b)+\sin(a-b)$$

Applied here: $$2\sin5x\cos4x=\sin(5x+4x)+\sin(5x-4x)=\sin9x+\sin x$$

Comment: I can move terms from one side to another as long as both side are equal right?

Comment: Yes, indeed! Just as I took the identity above, subtracted $\sin^2 \theta$ from both sides of the identity $\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta = 1$

Comment: Are you asking specifically about the identity in question (that you solved)? Or about trig identities in general? I took your question to refer to "in general". If you don't find my answer helpful, I can delete it.

Comment: Yes, my question was general and yes your answer is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** We have $\sin 5x\cos 4x+\cos 5x\sin 4x=\sin 9x$. Replace **one** of the $\sin 5x\cos 4x$ by $\sin 9x-\cos 5x\sin 4x$. Leave the other one alone. Something nice will happen.

You will end up  having used the basic addition **and** subtraction laws 
$$\sin(a\pm b)=\sin a\cos b\pm \cos a\sin b.$$

Comment: In fact, the "subtraction" laws are just a matter of substituting $-b$ into the "addition" laws, which is why I don't consider them worth mentioning.

Comment: @pre-kidney: True, but in this context it serves to extend the hint.

Answer (score 1):

The intended techniques all follow from using the sine and cosine addition formulas and normalization, which you should have seen before.

However, I wanted to point out that a more unified approach to the general problem of proving trig. identities is to work in the complex plane. For instance $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$ allows you to derive identities such as $\cos(x)=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$ and $\sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$.
Let $w=e^{ix}$. Then you can turn your identity into an equivalent "factorization problem" for a sparse polynomial in $w$, of degree $18$.

Try it out!

Comment: Working in the complex plane is not an option because we haven't learned that yet.

Comment: Then as I said, all your techniques will follow from addition formulas and normalization. Also, I checked your "identity", and it does not hold. Is there a typo somewhere? In case you meant "equation", not "identity", I checked for roots and saw that it didn't have any computable ones, either.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin C+\sin D=2\sin\frac{C+D}2\cos\frac{C-D}2$$

So, $$\sin9x+\sin x=2\sin\frac{9x+x}2\cos\frac{9x-x}2=2\sin5x\cos4x$$

---

$$2\sin A\cos B=\sin(A+B)+\sin(A-B)$$

So, $$2\sin5x\cos4x=\sin(5x+4x)+\sin(5x-4x)=\sin9x+\sin x$$

Comment: Observe that the two formulae are related and one can be easily derived from the other.